# Does Installing a driver increase linux kernel memory footprint?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel

I have read that linux kernel is monolithic kernel and it contains drivers within it, in a single file.

For example, I have two linux kernels 3.16.0.40 and 3.16.0.50
Currently booted system with 3.16.0.40 and installed for e.g nvidia driver

Does the driver is pushed in a kernel ?

If so, If I select 3.16.0.50 from grub and boot a system

Can it access the currently installed driver from previous kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux kernel is monolithic indeed, but it also utilizes some micro-kernel features. One of those is [loadable kernel modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module) support. So linux kernel has 2 options for driver:

- driver can be [built-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux#Design); those drivers will reside inside of kernel image file, which is `/boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)`
- driver can be [loadable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module); those drivers are separate files;
   look at `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/*`

So in your case you are gonna have two video drivers (files) in your system, one for each kernel version. And only one driver will be used, for the version of kernel you are running at the moment.

Comment: So newly installed driver does not increase kernel memory footprint? Or it depends on driver vendor  ? and switching between linux kernels does not affect the software which needs that driver?

Comment: Only one video driver will be loaded, for the version of kernel you are running. So the answer is no, memory footprint (RAM) will **not** be increased, if you are installing some drivers for another kernel version.

Comment: If drivers are loadable also so why we need two instances for different kernels ?

Comment: @AbdulRehman you will only have one instance of kernel running at any one time, from the point of boot up to userland space.

Comment: @AbdulRehman Because different versions of kernel have different [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). So you need to have your video driver compiled against each of kernel you have, so they can play nice together.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful :-), But I will wait for more answers @SamProtsenko

Comment: @AbdulRehman Actually you can try and load module built for different kernel version, and if you are happy -- it will work. You just need to do `modprobe -f` to ignore so called **vermagic** string. But for driver as complex as video driver -- you are almost definitely gonna have some errors (module oops or kernel crash, because of mismatch in ABI).

Comment: @AbdulRehman Sure, by all means, I'm not pushing you, take your time :) You may also consider asking this question on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/), as your question is not really about programming, so it belongs more to superuser than to stackoverflow. Might have more answers there than here.

Comment: I have questioned this on superuser.com, Thanks for your help :-) @SamProtsenko